# How can I retrieve users who have performed specific events in Mixpanel's Arb Database using JQL?

Tags: javascript, json, nosql

I have been recently working with Mixpanel's **Javascript Query Language** in order to analyze user behaviour. I have come up with 2 different variations of the query for the problem statement mentioned below but none of it seems to be working for me. Out of which one I am posting below. Can anybody suggest me the correct way to write the query in order to get the required result.

**Problem Statement**: Find all distinct id's of user who have performed events "xyz", "abc" & "dfg".

**Database In JSON Format** (with dummy data, the actual database is much larger with data in same format):

```
[
    {
        "name": "xyz",
        "distinct_id": "121"
    },

    {
        "name": "abc",
        "distinct_id": "345"
    }
]
```

**Query I wrote:**

```
function main() {
    return Events({
        from_date: "2017-06-26",
        to_date: "2017-06-27"
    })
    .groupByUser(function(state, events) {

        var flag_abc = false, flag_xyz = false, flag_dfg = false,  count_unique = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < events.length - 1; i ++){

            if (count_unique === 3){
                state = true;
                return state;
            }

            if (events[i].name === "abc" && !flag_abc ){
                count_unique += 1;
                flag_abc = true;
            }
            else if(events[i].name === "xyz" && !flag_xyz){
                count_unique += 1;
                flag_xyz = true;
            }
            else if(events[i].name === "dfg" && !flag_dfg){
                count_unique += 1;
                flag_dfg = true;
            }
      }
      state = false;
      return state;
  })
  .filter(function(arr){
     if(arr.value === false)
         return false;
     else
         return true;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code has limitations

```
for (var i = 0; i < events.length - 1; i ++){
    if (count_unique === 3){
        state = true;
        return state;
    }
    if (events[i].name === "abc" && !flag_abc ){
        count_unique += 1;
        flag_abc = true;
    }
    else if(events[i].name === "xyz" && !flag_xyz){
        count_unique += 1;
        flag_xyz = true;
    }
    else if(events[i].name === "dfg" && !flag_dfg){
        count_unique += 1;
        flag_dfg = true;
    }
}
```

You are assuming that your JSON has only 2 distinct type (xyz, abc ).
what if you have more unique names. you will have to modify your code each time

Better approach is

have a global variable and keep adding all unique names to it.
eg:

```
var data = ["12", "14", "12", "11"];
console.log(jQuery.unique( data ));

gives : ["12", "14", "11"]

count_unique => will be size of array 
flag_abc  => check if in array abc exist
```

Comment: I am not looking for optimizations. I am looking for an alternative way to write the same thing in JQL which works. Right now this query retrieves wrong result even though the logic seems correct to me. Anybody who is acquainted to Mixpanel's JQL, or is actually using it,  your help would be appreciated.

Comment: The JQL I am talking about here is actually writing native javascript code to query your database and is different from jquery.